# Apollo - endpoint http not found in root project

Tags: android, apollo

I am trying to load a schema through introspection: according to the [docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/android/tutorial/02-add-the-graphql-schema/) I should run the following in my project root directory:

```
mkdir -p app/src/main/graphql/com/example/rocketreserver/ ./gradlew :app:downloadApolloSchema -Pcom.apollographql.apollo.endpoint='https://apollo-fullstack-tutorial.herokuapp.com/' -Pcom.apollographql.apollo.schema='src/main/graphql/com/example/rocketreserver/schema.json'
```

So, I changed it to:

```
mkdir -p app/src/main/graphql/com/myapp/ ./gradlew :app:downloadApolloSchema -Pcom.apollographql.apollo.endpoint='http://localhost:4000/graphql/' -Pcom.apollographql.apollo.schema='src/main/graphql/com/myapp/schema.json'
```

However I'm getting the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
    Project '.apollographql.apollo.endpoint=http' not found in root project 'MyApp'.
```

I've added the apollo plugin in the app level gradle file:

```
id("com.apollographql.apollo").version("2.3.1")
```

I've also registered the task like:

```
tasks.register("downloadSchema", com.apollographql.apollo.gradle.internal.ApolloDownloadSchemaTask.class) {
    endpointUrl.set("https://localhost:4000/graphql")
    schemaFilePath.set("src/main/graphql/com/myapp/schema.json")
}
```

I'm not sure what the error means exactly, I've searched for it, but can't find a reference or a solution.

**Note:** I get the same error when I try to run the exact same command given in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the command posted in the docs is wrong, it should be:

```
mkdir -p app/src/main/graphql/com/bangenergy/ ./gradlew :app:downloadApolloSchema -P com.apollographql.apollo.endpoint='http://localhost:4000/graphql/' -P com.apollographql.apollo.schema='src/main/graphql/com/bangenergy/schema.json'
```

Notice the space between `-P` and `com`.

Answer (score 0):

**This is the Windows Command**

```
gradlew :app:downloadApolloSchema --endpoint="http://****REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_ENDPOINT/graphql/" --schema="src/main/graphql/com/example/programbuilder/schema.json"
```

Also the  com.apollographql.apollo.schema deprecated with --schema and com.apollographql.apollo.endpoint deprecated with --endpoint